# JasperReport integration with keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, keycloak, jasperserver

Please, I am working on integrating jasper server with keycloak. Currently I am experiencing difficulties. Please does anyone have a clue that can help me?

We referred below link to enable oauth2 authentication of jasper server community edition using third party authentication https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-oauth-20-tibco-jasperreports-server. But it is not working. We are unable to configure following properties correctly: